# UITableView doesn't appear correctly - why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I use Xcode 5 and storyboard where I use navigation controller and table view, and in the following code called `RootViewController.h`,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController
@property NSMutableArray *objects;
@end
```

and `RootViewController.m`,

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_objects addObjectsFromArray:@[@"Apple",@"Google",@"Intel"]];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%d", _objects.count);
    return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"A";

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Xcode says "Build Succeeded" but the resultant screen doesn't have the rows rendered correctly.
It returns empty rows and title called `Root View Controller`.

Why?
I think I correctly write the three required method in `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and `numberOfSectionInTableView`, and I don't think I need to define protocol in header file since it's already defined in the parent `UITableViewController`.

And for some reasons the debug NSLog function in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method isn't executed.

So what am I missing here? And how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You said that numberOfRowsInSection isn't called. That's strange. Are any of the other data source methods called? Such as cellForRow and numberOfSection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create objects before you can add anything to it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _objects = [NSMutableArray new];
    [_objects addObjectsFromArray:@[@"Apple",@"Google",@"Intel"]];
}
```

Comment: So I can't define it in header file and just write it only in implementation file, right?

Comment: @user2360798, you can declare the property either in the .h file or in the class extension at the top of the .m file (if you don't want it to be seen from outside this file). Either way, you still need to create the object with alloc init, or new, or one of the other array creation methods.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `_objects` is nil - when you try to add objects to nothing the result is nothing.

So you need to create the array instead of adding to it. Change this line

```
[_objects addObjectsFromArray:@[@"Apple",@"Google",@"Intel"]];
```

to this

```
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Google", @"Intel", nil];
```

In your storyboard, you also need to set the cell identifier of the UITableViewCell (tutorials galore on how to do this).

Comment: It returns a warning `Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArray * from NSArray *`, and that's why I changed the latter to the former.

Comment: Also, even if I ignore the warning and ran the code, then I got the following error: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`. What does this mean?

Comment: Open your storyboard-> click to cell--> Show the attributes inspector(on the right side)-> type to identifier "Cell"

Answer (score 0):

Put inside `viewDidLoad`

```
self.title = @"some title";
```

To change the title of NavigationBar

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I answered how to change the title from Root View Controller to something else, since he mentioned it. The others adequately answered the other part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the tableview delegate? Did you set the tableviewcell correctly in storyboard?